# GLFW OpenGL window slow to update on resize?

Tags: c++, opengl, x11, glfw, window-resize

I have a simple triangle program:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include<glad/glad.h>
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include<iostream>


void framebuffer_resize_callback(GLFWwindow *window,int width,int height)
{
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);   
}
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
    }
}
void render()
{
    glClearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
}

void opengl_setup(void)
{
    float verticies[] = {
        -0.5,-0.5,0.0,
        0.5,-0.5,0.0,
        0.0,0.5,0.0
    };
    unsigned int VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1,&VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    unsigned int VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1,&VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(verticies),verticies,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    const char *vertexshadersource = "#version 460 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x,aPos.y,aPos.z,1.0);\n"
    "}\0";

    unsigned int vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader,1,&vertexshadersource,NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&success);

    if(!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader,512,NULL,infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION FAILED\n" << infoLog;
    }

    unsigned int fragmentShader;
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    char *fragmentshadersource = "#version 460 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.5,0.2,1.0);\n"
    "}\0";
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader,1,&fragmentshadersource,NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

   
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&success);

    if(!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader,512,NULL,infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION FAILED\n" << infoLog;
    }

    unsigned int shaderProgram;
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram,vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram,fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram,GL_LINK_STATUS,&success);

    if(!success)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram,512,NULL,infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM::LINKING FAILED\n" << infoLog;
    }

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,3*sizeof(float),(void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    
   

}
int main(void)
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if(window == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: could not create window!\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    if(!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: could not init glad\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_resize_callback);
    
    glViewport(0,0,800,600);
    opengl_setup();
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        processInput(window);
        render();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

...however the render of the triangle slightly lags behind the resizing of the window.

I used `glGetString(GL_RENDERER)` to confirm that openGL is using my AMD Radeon RX 570 and not the software renderer, so I don't know what might be causing this issue.

Can anyone help explain this lag drawing a triangle of 3 vertices?

System: Fedora 38, OpenGl 4.6, AMD Radeon RX 570

Comment: The lag is to be expected and is not coming from your program but either from glfw and/or from the OS implementation of the window manager.

Comment: Which windowing system are you using, if any?  X11?  Wayland?  If Wayland, which compositor?

Comment: You'd have a bigger problem on Windows: freezing the application completely until it finishes resizing, unless you go out of your way to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'm using X11. The fact this this is probably the windowing system is surprising to me, but now that you mention it, I have noticed similar issues using 3D applications like Blender or Maya. Both powerful 3D engines but have lag when resizing. In fact I've noticed Maya uses empty lines when dragging panels, only to render them when I release the mouse.

Comment: Consider adding a window resize callback: [`glfwSetWindowSizeCallback`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_size). Note that screen and framebuffer (pixel) dimensions are not necessarily the same. Also consider setting: `glfwSwapInterval(1)` so you're not  generating more frames than your refresh rate.

Comment: Ah thanks for this advice. That doesn't seem to reduce the lag on my system, but I guess that's the norm for these things.